# Finitely generated projective modules over the algebra of sections of the Clifford bundle

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, clifford-algebras

Consider a (pseudo-)Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$ and the corresponding [Clifford bundle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clifford_bundle) $Cl_g(T^*M)$. Let $R$ be the algebra of sections of $CL_g(T^*M)$, with point-wise multiplication. What are the <s>simple</s> finitely generated projective modules over $R$ (I realized that simple modules may not have a nice interpretation in terms of bundles)? If $S$ is such a module, is it projective as a module over $C^\infty(M)\subset R$? And if so, what is the structure of the vector bundle on $M$ that $S$ corresponds to ([Serre-Swan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serre%E2%80%93Swan_theorem))?

I believe its pretty straight forward that given a spin structure on $(M,g)$ (that is, a $\mathrm{Spin}_g$-principal bundle on $M$), an associated bundle of an irreducible spinor representation of the $\mathrm{Spin}_g$ group defines precisely a finitely generated projective $R$-module. But what about the case when $(M,g)$ has no spin structures?